# ClassCastException error here

Tags: java, xml, database, tags, classcastexception

i got an error code when I try and read/print out an xml database -

here's the code for the file -

```
 package xml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MyDomParser {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("C://users/user/desktop/xml/xml/src/xml/people.xml");
        NodeList personList = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
        for (int i=0; i<personList.getLength(); i++){
            Node p = personList.item(i);
            if(p.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element person = (Element) p;
                String id = (String) ((DocumentBuilderFactory)person).getAttribute("id");
                NodeList nameList = ((Node)person).getChildNodes();
                for(int j=0; j< ((NodeList)nameList).getLength(); j++){
                    Node n = nameList.item(j);
                    if(n.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                        Element name = (Element) n;
                        System.out.println("Person " + id + ":" + name.getSimpleName() + "=" + ((Node)name).getTextContent());

                    }

                }
            //  ((Document) r).getAttributes().getNamedItem("author").getNodeValue()
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }   catch (SAXException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }   catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

here's the error message I get when I execute and try and run the above code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.Element
at xml.MyDomParser.main(MyDomParser.java:27)
```

What could be wrong with my code? I am using the Eclipse IDE to type and edit my code in. Should I use another IDE?

The "people.xml" file can also be seen below:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>

<people>

<person id ="1">
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    </person>
    <person id="2">
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>

    <firstname>Jim</firstname>
    </person>
</people>
```

That's a small xml file with just a few name tags but I can't even get the code to execute properly because of the ClassCastException error. Any takes on this? Thanks a mill for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

you import error Element,should be org.w3c.dom.Element

Comment: that doesn't work...on my file at least...does the java version matter in this case?